# Excel power view is not working on my computer

Tags: excel

When i try to create a power view report it just generates the following image:
[image]

Only after i close and re-open the excel i get the power View tab, but this image is still there and the data i want to visualize is not. Does anyone knows how to fix this issue?

i found only 1 related page on the net but this solution does not make a lot of sense, and anyway it only works with 2 computers:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother-mso_2013_release/excel-powerview-error-image/28564661-ebc1-426c-8f56-e6bb96d14d4a

Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Best regards,
Mihail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might need this in the future.

1. You need to install Silverlight on your computer: https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/Get-Started/Install/Default
2. If issue is till not fixed, install the enable controls from here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Registry-keys-to-reenable-7cd9f723

Now it should work!

Best regards,
Mihail

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me in Excel from MS Office Professional Plus 2016.

I downloaded the EnableControls pack and executed EnableSilverLight.reg.

Then I was able to click the Power View button and create a "Power View1" tab, but instead of Power View panes I get only that same image.

But then I found, by this (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/powerview-image-error-in-office-365-online/81baa2c5-1c9c-4d36-b424-60ad59696005) answer in Microsoft Community, that I didn't had SilverLight installed.

After installing by Mihail's link (item 1) it worked fine!